# How do I add UILabel to UIScroll View using the Storyboard?

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am trying to add a UILabel onto a scroll view, so that when I scroll, the contents will move but the label will not. How do I do this in the story board without messing up the constraints of the scrollview?

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the label inside the scroll view (the first picture), but rather inside the scroll view's parent view (the second picture)

[image]
[image]

So now the label's position will be relative to the parent view and not the scroll view. Then you can just control+click+drag from the label to the scroll view and choose your constraints from there.